# switching between fragments delete the views in first fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have in my app a drawer navigation, which contain few fragments to go to. when my app starts it opens by default the first fragment - which contains a view pager that has 2 fragments in it as well. in those 2 fragments I have a text view and a button as well.
the problem is that if I click on another fragment in the drawer, and then go back to the first fragment, the button and the text view are gone. in the first time this view pager fragment is creating the two other fragments. I think that when I go back to this fragment again by replacing it, it wont load the other two fragments and their text and button view. I'm going crazy because of this and I cant continue my work..what is wrong here?

**I don't know how to upload code snippets..sorry**

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: to upload a snippet, copy the code, highlight it and hit ctrl+k

Comment: Thanks! ill remember that.
can you help me with this problem?

Comment: You should add your code (just copy-paste [in the text area](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34404048/edit)), but I'm guessing that you are returning a new Fragment instance each time you are switching pages in the ViewPager.

Comment: Alright i solved the problem! the problem was instantiating the adapter of the view pager..i used the wrong parameter there..i needed to use the getChildFragmentManager and the regular..the view pager is cool element but not easy to handle